# A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type in mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is quite strange but I m getting this error `A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type` on the following line in a controller action method

```
int[] Numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; or I have also tried
var Numbers = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

Also tried few other ways of getting this line work but it won't.

Other than controller action methods this works perfectly fine. Any ideas about this weird behavior?

I m using VS 2013 express edition MVC version 5 and .net framework 4.5

Here is complete action method

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var LstMainModel=new List<MainModel>           
        var ids = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};            
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            LstMainModel.Add(new MainModel{Id=id,planeModel=GetPlanes()});
        }

        return View(LstMainModel);
    }
```

Comment: Can you check, don't you have class named `Numbers` in your project?

Comment: Something else is at play here. The declarations are correct

Comment: I have tried changing the variable name and no class with Numbers at all

Comment: Can you show the entire method that includes this?

Comment: maby this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/389775/1849444) can help you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `List` is wrong.

`var LstMainModel = new List<MainModel>`

Should be

`var LstMainModel = new List<MainModel>();`

**Here is a working example:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var results = TestMethod();
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
                Console.WriteLine(item.planeModel);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }

        static List<MainModel> TestMethod()
        {
            var LstMainModel = new List<MainModel>();    
            var ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                LstMainModel.Add(new MainModel { Id = id, planeModel = "TestPlane" });
            }

            return LstMainModel;
        }


    }

    class MainModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string planeModel { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Also you can re-write the `foreach` to a LINQ Expression, which in my opinion becomes more readable in this case.

```
static List<MainModel> TestMethod()
{
    var ids = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    return ids.Select(id => new MainModel {Id = id, planeModel = GetPlanes()}).ToList();
}

static String GetPlanes()
{
    return "PlanesTest";
}
```

Comment: I mentioned it works every where else other than an action method in a controller

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you have it but if not,

try like this: (declaring size of the array)

```
int[] numbers = new int[5] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

If it still doesn't work the problem is something else